# Detecting Change jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

So I have this notification system that uses jQuery and PHP. The jQuery checks the PHP script every few seconds, and if there is a change, it is displayed. I want to know how to detect a change in the data (like from '1' to '2') and then responding by causing the object to animate (using this: $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300);). How can I do this?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.get('/codes/php/nf.php', function(data
{
$('#badge').badger(data);});});
setInterval(function(){
$.get('/codes/php/nf.php', function(data) 
{
$('#badge').badger(data);});}, 8000);
```

Comment: The usual way is to have the PHP script return a JSON string, the contents of which you parse in your JavaScript and then animate (or not) based on the resulting data.

Comment: Essentially you'd want to use logic like, as an extremely broad example, `if ($('#badge').getData() != data) {`, though I'm not exactly sure what "badger" does with the returned data, or if you can easily pull it out to compare it again once it's been set.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the data and how does the object look like?

Comment: An example of what `data` contains would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect change on your PHP script, and depending on change in data (ie whether data has changed or not), you could pass in appropriate value to your js script and process accordingly..